# How to set ErrorMessage on TextField dynamically on Button onClick method

Tags: reactjs, spfx, office-fabric

I need to bind ErrorMessage to textfield only when user press button. In this there are nice examples how to use errormessage but the problem is that I don't know how to make append errorMeesage after user click

```
 <TextField id='titleField' value={titleValue} required={true} label={escape(this.props.description)} onGetErrorMessage={this._getErrorMessage} validateOnLoad={false} />
```

And this is a call of a button:

```js
private _buttonOnClickHandler() {
    let textvalue = document.getElementById('titleField')["value"];

    if(textvalue === "")
    {
        //call onGetErrorMessage or something that will set ErrorMeesage and input will be red
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I can think of to accomplish this is by predicating the `onGetErrorMessage` on a state check, which tracks whether the button has been clicked.

```js
<TextField
    id='titleField'
    value={titleValue}
    required={true}
    label={escape(this.props.description)}
    // Only allow showing error message, after determining that user has clicked the button
    onGetErrorMessage={this.state.buttonHasBeenClicked ? this._getErrorMessage : undefined}
    validateOnLoad={false}
/>
```

Then in your button click handler, simply set that state value:

```js
private _buttonOnClickHandler() {
    this.setState({ buttonHasBeenClicked: true });

    return false;
}
```

As long as you instantiate `buttonHasBeenClicked` to be false, then this method will meet the requirement that (a) before the user clicks the button, no error messages are shown by the `TextField`, and (b) after the user clicks the button, error messages start to be shown. You retain the ability to use `_getErrorMessage(value)` to customize the error message based upon the current value in the `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set state for displaying/hiding error messages based on user input, Check below code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isErrorMessageHidden: true
  }
  clickHandler = () => {
    let textValue = document.getElementById('titleField').value;
    if(textValue === '')
      this.setState({isErrorMessageHidden: false});
    else
      this.setState({isErrorMessageHidden: true});    
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Check</button>
       <input type='text' id='titleField' />
       <p 
          style={{'color':'red'}}
          hidden={this.state.isErrorMessageHidden}
        >Please fill the form</p>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach would be to handle all the validations via state values.

The control definition goes like this

```
<TextField placeholder="Enter a venue location" required onChange={this._onVenueChange} {...this.state.errorData.isValidVenue ? null : { errorMessage: strings.RequiredFieldErrorMessage }}></TextField>
```

On the Onchange event, you validate the control's value and set the error state value as below,

```
private _onVenueChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string): void => {

this.setState(prevState => ({
  errorData: {
    ...prevState.errorData,
    isValidVenue: newValue && newValue.length > 0,
    isValidForm: this.state.errorData.isValidForm && newValue && newValue.length > 0
  }
}));

this.setState(prevState => ({
  formData: {
    ...prevState.formData,
    venue: newValue
  }
}));
}
```

In the above example, I am using two objects within states, one for capturing the values and other for capturing whether the field is error-ed or not.

Hope this helps..

Cheers!!!